# function is not defined (selenium / python)

Tags: selenium

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
t = 'test'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script('function myFunction(token) { alert(token); }')
driver.execute_script('myFunction(' + t + ');')
driver.close()
```

error is
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

not sure what im doing wrong since the function works fine outside of selenium

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to put both JS executions in single block:

```
driver.execute_script("""function myFunction(token) { alert(token);};
                         myFunction(' + t + ');""")
```

Answer (score 0):

For write new functions or rewrite exist functions you must use `window`.

for example below function alert 'hello' in console.

```
function myFunction(){
 alert('hello!' );
 }
```

In selenium you must use `window` code as shown as :

```
funccc="""
window.myFunction= function (){
    alert('hello!' );
     }

driver.execute_script(funccc)
```

Then myFunction is defined.